# Freemarker converts < to &lt;

Tags: html, cross-browser, freemarker

So I have this issue where there is a variable {item.item} This item.item contains a string like 'abc < 5'. this < is getting converted into &_lt; while the template runs in browser. I tried to work with escape with no luck. What finally worked for me is using a code snippet like below:

<#assign x = "${item.item}" />
              ${x}

This is returning the string correctly, but I am struggling to accept this as a solution. Any inputs ?

Comment: Can you post how you were using the escape?

Comment: Thanks tony !  <td colspan="6">
    <#escape x as x?html>
  ${item.item}     
    </#escape> 
    </td>.. I guess the purpose of <escape> is to convert < to &_lt; right ?

Comment: Does nlapiEscapeXML ( text ) help ? How to use it in above code snippet ?

Comment: I don't know jack about Freemarker, but http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html says to use `\l` for less than.

Comment: Not sure about that ! As i will need to do a replace in {item.item} for < to \l.. dont think thats a good idea

Comment: Well, when you're in Rome you have to deal with Romans.  If you're taking strings of data and putting them into things that have reserved characters, then you have to deal with it one way or the other.  Pick your poison.  :)

Comment: `<#assign x = "${item.item}" /> ${x}` does nothing as far as escaping goes, it shouldn't make a difference. If you are inside `<#escape x as x?html>...</#escape>`, Freemarker will escape the output of all `${...}`-s that are outside Freemarker tags. You can prevent that like `<#noescape>${...}</#noescape>`. Does that explain it?

Comment: Yes ddekany ! <#noescape> solved my issue. thanks a million :)!